Name of a particular post-hoc statistical fallacy
There is a surprisingly common statistical/logical error where someone picks an element from a large random sample that has some special properties and ascribes a unique origin to it as a result of those properties.
One famous example is the "Face on Mars," where among the many random hills and geologic formations on Mars photographed by Viking 1 spacecraft, one appears like a human face.  Sober scientists had to explain to a gullible general public that this structure was not some alien artwork but that something "face-like" is bound to occur in a sufficiently large random dataset.
Other common examples are include when an image of Christ appears in unevenly toasted bread and some naive people ascribe it as a religious sign... "from heaven."
As context:  Mathematician John Nash studied how to calculate a particular configuration of random points (say) would contain a particular spatial pattern (e.g., a square, or the outline of a teapot).  Suppose in some deep space astrophotograph we find stars or galaxies in the pattern of the McDonald's restaurant double-arch logo.  Would we conclude that there is something in the universe that deliberately placed this corporate logo?  Of course not...  Given enough random stars, we're BOUND to find some stars that fall into that double-arch pattern.
To believe that the McDonald's logo was "deliberately designed and placed in the heavens" would be a fallacy.
THAT's the fallacy I need named.

In which context is this a statistical falacy? Are you thinking like the human being bad at recognising and generating random sequences. E.g. considering a royal flush as more special and less likely than any other random hand.

If you are looking for the statistical term it is a Type I error also known as a false positive.

No no no.  The is certainly not "type I error."  that's a separate concept entirely.  An error is not a fallacy at all, for instance.  Even in the best (Bayes) classifier there will be type I (and type II) errors.  I'm describing is a LOGICAL or METHODOLOGICAL fallacy in failing to realize that you happen to choose a particular pattern a posteriori.

It's the good old looking at the data before making the hypothesis fallacy.
The fair way to do it is hypothesize the probability of finding the McDonalds logo, then search the stars and do the counting. Not the other way around.

I'm reminded of the watchmaker argument which is a teleological argument. I'm not sure 'teleological fallacy' is accepted as a fallacy by everyone but there are a lot of writings arguing against the idea. You might find a useful term in that space.

This fallacy is seeing signal from noise.

There are several related terms/concepts

Seeing special meaning in unrelated things (like: face = meaning, unrelated = rocks in a random pile) is 'apophenia'.

When it it is recognising faces then it is called 'pareidolia'.

A special case related to statistics/randomness is the 'clustering illusion'. Clusters or patterns in random distributions are considered unlikely.



Creating arguments that lead to a predetermined conclusion could be 'begging the question'.

The behaviour to look for causal explanations in coincidentally occurring events is called 'synchronicity'.

The 'look elsewhere effect' is the effect that the probability of a significant result is increased when we look multiple times for such significant result.


In the comments you state that the look elsewhere effect is what you were looking for. But that is solely the fallacy of a false expression of the probability of an event/effect occurring (by considering a single test and ignoring multiple times looking in other tests).
The assignment of a special causal meaning to such improbable/random event (which actually was probable, or even when it was improbable even when accounting for the look elsewhere effect, then it might still be a random event) is more related to apophenia and synchronicity.

This certainly isn't "synchronicity."  There are no two events happening "at the same time."  Although pareidolia happens to refer to face recognition, that is entirely irrelevant to the central question at hand.  Nor is this "begging the question," as nobody a priori said there would be a face on Mars and then went out and found it.  See?

@DavidG.Stork could you explain the central question a bit better. Because of your two examples, I thought you were speaking about the fallacy of recognising faces where they are not.

Other related terms are the 'look elsewhere effect' and 'clustering illusion'.

YEP... that's it:  "Look Elsewhere effect."  (I had never heard that term.)  Put it in your answer and I'll accept.  Thanks so much!

Synchronicity, there are multiple events happening at the same time and they create the illusion of a human face. Ascribing a unique origin to it, rather than coincidence, is the case described by synchronicity.

Look "elsewhere effect" it is ($\checkmark$).  Thanks!

I would interpret these as examples of the famous Texas sharpshooter fallacy.
From wiki,

The Texas sharpshooter fallacy often arises when a person has a large amount of data at their disposal but only focuses on a small subset of that data. Some factor other than the one attributed may give all the elements in that subset some kind of common property (or pair of common properties, when arguing for correlation). If the person attempts to account for the likelihood of finding some subset in the large data with some common property by a factor other than its actual cause, then that person is likely committing a Texas sharpshooter fallacy.
The fallacy is characterized by a lack of a specific hypothesis prior to the gathering of data, or the formulation of a hypothesis only after data have already been gathered and examined.

This popular article on the faces in Mars discusses it as a sharpshooter fallacy.

I used to think it was the Texas sharpshooter fallacy but then decided  that, while closely related, it wasn't quite right.  The reason is that nobody chose the McDonald's arches ahead of time (i.e., "shot" and shot).  See?

This sounds to me like "data-dredging"
I would say that this is probably best understood as an example of data dredging, which occurs when a user dredges through a large amount of data to find some unusual pattern that appears to be "significant" when looked at in isolation.  The examples you give involve observing a single unusual case with some unusual property of interest amongst a large number of sampled cases, and then assessing the statistical properties post hoc without proper consideration of the mechanism by which it was sampled (i.e., the fact that it was pulled from a large sample precisely because it had the unusual properties of interest).
Observing a hill that resembles a human face is unusual, but it is obviously much less unusual if you observe thousands of hills and choose the one that is most "face-like".  Similarly, a piece of toast with the image of Christ is unusual, but it is much less unusual if you generate thousands of pieces of toast and then choose the one that is most "Christ-like" (or more broadly, like any other image of significance).  From a statistical perspective, good practice in making inference from such cases would take account of the full sampling mechanism, not just the presence of a single unusual case.  When a user ignores the full sampling mechanism and assesses a single case post hoc (as if it arose from taking a single observation at random) this is data dredging that biases their inference heavily in favour of a false positive.  (If combined with a formal statistical hypothesis test we also call this "p-hacking" since the p-value of the test is "hacked" to a much lower value by ignoring the true sampling mechanism.)

The face on Mars is a bit different. It was a:
Hasty (or Faulty) Generalization Fallacy

This fallacy occurs when an argument is based on a body of evidence that is simply too small. 1

The so-called face on Mars was an artifact of the extremely low resolution of the pictures taken of the surface of Mars; once higher resolution pictures became available, no such feature was seen to be present on Cydonia. Below was the updated image, provided by NASA:

No pareidolia here!

Would you mind explaining what "the argument" refers to and what specifically was being generalized?

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
